# Git not recognizing remote branches?

Tags: git, github, version-control

I'm a little new to git/github and I'm having an issue with pushing my changes to a new branch. Here's some relevant context before I get into it:

**Remote Branches**

- main
- test_deploy

**Inputs/Outputs**

`git status`:
`On branch test_deploy nothing to commit, working tree clean`

`git branch -vv`:

```
master      e6c262d find out why case switch doesnt work
* test_deploy e6c262d find out why case switch doesnt work
```

`git branch -r`:

```
origin/main
origin/test_deploy
```

**Problem**

After committing changes, I try to push with `git push origin test_deploy` but I'm met with:

```
 ! [rejected]        test_deploy -> test_deploy (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/user/project_API.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

**What I've tried**

1. `git pull` which outputs `There is no tracking information for the current branch. Please specify which branch you want to merge with.`
2. `git pull test_deploy` which outputs

   ```
   fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

   Please make sure you have the correct access rights
   and the repository exists.
   ```
3. `git merge test_deploy` which outputs `Already up to date.`
4. `git rebase test_deploy` which outputs `Current branch test_deploy is up to date.`
5. Deleting github credits manager and reinstalling it
6. `git reset -hard` which didnt seem to solve anything
7. Deleting the .git folder and reinitializing the remote

**Conclusion**

I feel like a chimp in a space shuttle because I don't know what buttons to press anymore. If someone could give me pointers as to whats happening and why I can't push, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: 2. should have been `git pull origin test_deploy`.

Comment: Or better https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520650/make-an-existing-git-branch-track-a-remote-branch, so you don't have to specify which remote branch you are referring to.

Comment: Can you show the output of your hidden .git/config file?